# how do I design a loop that accepts user input for a golfer name and their score then displays list?

Tags: java

I would like this program to loop until the user inputs "Z". I have designed it with the yes or no question just to that it would work, but I do not want that. I want it to ask for golfer and score over and over until the user inputs "Z". I then want all the names and scores I entered to display in a list format. I feel like I am pretty close but a newbie here needs some help! Thank you for any and all responses.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class golfTournament {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String golfer, answer;
    int score;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter player name. (Enter Z to terminate)");

        golfer = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("Enter score");
        score = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another golfer and score? Yes or No");
        answer = keyboard.next();
    } while (answer.equals("Yes"));

    System.out.println("Player: " + golfer + "\t\tScore: " + score);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you were pretty close this is it:

```
    String golfer, answer;
    int score;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter player name. (Enter Z to terminate)");
        golfer = keyboard.next();
        if (!golfer.equals("Z")) {
            System.out.println("Enter score");
            score = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        
    } while (!golfer.equals("Z"));

    System.out.println("Player: " + golfer + "\t\tScore: " + score);
```

Comment: That is the loop I needed with the if statement nested in it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem dude plz consider accepting my answer so both me and you earn reputation and community knows your problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

To implement the ability to enter `Z` for a golfer name to end the entry process, you can check for that condition and then exit the golfer entry loop with a `break` statement.

To save the scores, you need two things: 1) some way of storing a golfer name and a a golf score together, and 2) a way of collecting a group of names and scores in a single place.

To solve the first problem, you can define a very simple class named `Golfer` to store the golfer's name and score.  Then, you can create an `ArrayList` to store `Golfer` objects.  For each name/score pair that your user inputs, you create a `Golfer` object and add it to your list.

Here's code that does all of these things:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class golfTournament {

    static class Golfer {
        String name;
        int score;

        Golfer(String name, int score) {
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Golfer> scores = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter player name. (Enter Z to terminate)");
            String golfer = keyboard.next();
            if (golfer.toLowerCase().equals("z"))
                break;

            System.out.println("Enter score");
            int score = keyboard.nextInt();

            scores.add(new Golfer(golfer, score));
        }

        for (Golfer score : scores)
            System.out.println("Player: " + score.name + "  Score: " + score.score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right. I needed a way to store the golfer names and scores in an array.

Comment: Also, how would you format the user input to accept a space? For instance, if I typed a person's first and last name? Currently, it displays a InputMismatchException

Comment: disregard. I found the answer. I used .useDelimiter("\\n"); after the init Scanner